# How to retrieve data from db in couchdb

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I am trying to fetch data from couch and i follwed the code below

```
  var request = require('request')
var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984/user');
var url = 'http://127.77.3.1:5984/'
var db = 'users2/'
var id = 'document_id'



exports.insertdata = function (req, res) {
  var data = req.body;
  var item = { 
    name: data.name,
    skills: data.skills, 
    experience: data.experience 
  };

nano.insert(item,(err, result) => {
  if(!err){
    //awesome
  }if(result){
     console.log(result)
    response = {status:'success',data:result};
  }
  res.send(response);
  });
};


exports.getdata = function (req, res) {
  nano.getDoc('25f2b6d1e5b83887a42c74bc9b000647',(err, result) => {
  if(!err){
    //awesome
    console.log(err)
  }if(result){console.log(result)
    console.log('inserted')
    response = {status:'success',data:result};
  }
   res.send(response);
  });
};
```

I am getting the following error

```
nano.getDoc is not a function
```

I am trying to fetch data from couch and i follwed the above code,i am not sure about the commands ....can anyone please suggest me some help..........

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701464/how-to-rtrive-data-from-db-in-couchdb-nodejs/39773354#39773354) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need any improvements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getDoc` in `nano` as far as I know. There is `get`. Maybe try changing this:

```
nano.getDoc('25f2b6d1e5b83887a42c74bc9b000647', (err, result) => {
});
```

to:

```
nano.get('25f2b6d1e5b83887a42c74bc9b000647', (err, result) => {
});
```

and see if that works.

For example here is a simplest query to the CouchDB database that powers the `npm` registry:

```
var nano = require('nano');
var db = nano('https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry');

db.get('rsp', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Here `rsp` is the document id, which is a module's name on `npm`.

In your case it might work if you change `getDoc` to `get`. For other function names see the documentation at:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano